# Adding FedEx to shopping cart with PHP

Tags: php, fedex

Will apologize if this has already been asked. Please post a link if it has been. I need to add shipping to a shopping cart I created. What I want to have is when someone views their shopping cart, there will be a drop down menu with different shipment options (ground, over night, etc) and the cost for each one. Then, after the customer finishes paying, a shipping label will be produced for the package(s).

I've looked at the FedEx developers site, and searched for help on this, but haven't had any luck.

Thanks in advance for the help

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FedEx offers different web services that you can use. For displaying rates during the checkout process, you can use their Rate endpoint, see https://www.fedex.com/us/developer/web-services/process.html?tab=tab1. For purchasing labels, you need to use the Ship Service, see https://www.fedex.com/us/developer/web-services/process.html?tab=tab1#app-tab2.

If you're looking for a simpler solution, you can use [Shippo](https://goshippo.com) (https://goshippo.com). It's a REST API for FedEx that offers a dedicated Rate and Label creation endpoint and has a convenient PHP api library. I'm happy to help if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks for the response Simon. I registered at Shippo and downloaded the library. I uploaded that and edited example.php to include my login info. However, I am getting an error that states:

Comment: "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Shippo_AuthenticationError' with message '{"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."}' in \lib\Shippo\ApiRequestor.php:148 Stack trace: #0 \lib\Shippo\ApiRequestor.php(195): Shippo_ApiRequestor->handleApiError('{"detail": "Aut...', 401, Array) #1 \lib\Shippo\ApiRequestor.php(102): Shippo_ApiRequestor->_interpretResponse('{"detail": "Aut...', 401) #2 \lib\Shippo\ApiResource.php(107):

Comment: Shippo_ApiRequestor->request('post', '/v1/customs/dec...', Array) #3 \lib\Shippo\CustomsDeclaration.php(26): Shippo_ApiResource::_scopedCreate('Shippo_CustomsD...', Array, NULL) #4 \vtc in \lib\Shippo\ApiRequestor.php on line 148"

Comment: Sorry, had to break it apart, couldn't fit the whole thing in a comment. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Did you enter your username and password in line 8 of the example (Shippo::setCredentials("<USERNAME>", "<PASSWORD>"))? Feel free to reach out to support@goshippo.com, they're usually faster than I am on Stack Overflow :) but of course always happy to help myself

Comment: Thanks. I'll send them an email.